# Oracle client libraries missing in node-based docker image

Tags: docker

Here is my docker image

> FROM node:8-alpine
>   ADD oracle-instantclient*.rpm /tmp/
>   COPY . /app
>   WORKDIR /app
>   RUN npm install --production --no-optional
>   ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/
>   CMD ["node", "."]

I am getting error

> 1540183793466 Registered plugin: @axway/api-builder-plugin-fn-swagger
>   Failed to load connector sub directory module; skipping it:
>   Error: NJS-045: cannot load the oracledb add-on binary for Node.js 8.11.2 (linux, x64)

Node.js require() error was:

> DPI-1047: 64-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: "Error loading shared library libclntsh.so: No such file or directory". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#linux for help
>   Node.js require() mapped to /app/node_modules/@axway/api-builder-plugin-dc-oracle/node_modules/oracledb/build/Release/oracledb.node
>   Node-oracledb installation instructions: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html
>   You must have 64-bit Oracle client libraries in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, or configured with ldconfig.
>   If you do not have Oracle Database on this computer, then install the Instant Client Basic or Basic Light package from
>   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html
>   at Object. (/app/node_modules/@axway/api-builder-plugin-dc-oracle/node_modules/oracledb/lib/oracledb.js:65:13)
>   at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
>   at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
>   at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
>   at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
>   at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
>   at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>   at Object. (/app/node_modules/@axway/api-builder-plugin-dc-oracle/node_modules/oracledb/index.js:1:80)
>   at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
>   Failed to load connector sub directory module; skipping it:

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `.rpm` to your image is not sufficient to install the Oracle client.
You need to install it through a package manager.

That might not be easy, since you are using node:8-*alpine* as a base image.
I would suggest using the normal node image and installing the Oracle instantclient like so in your image:

```
FROM node:8
ADD oracle-instantclient*.rpm /tmp/

RUN  yum -y install /tmp/oracle-instantclient*.rpm && \
     rm -rf /var/cache/yum && \
     rm -f /tmp/oracle-instantclient*.rpm && \
     echo /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient12.2.conf && \
     ldconfig

ENV PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/bin

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install --production --no-optional
CMD ["node", "."]
```

For reference check [here](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/master/OracleInstantClient/dockerfiles/12.2.0.1/Dockerfile)

Comment: Or use the Oracle Instant Client image: https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleInstantClient  The 18.3 based image is a whole lot simpler now that [Oracle Instant Client 18.3 doesn't need a click through](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/oracle-instant-client-based-middle-tiers-such-as-docker-without-a-click-through) from yum.oracle.com.  Note that 18.3 clients can connect to the same DB versions as the 12.2 client.